How many vectors of $(x_1,.....,x_n)$ are there, such that each $x_i$ is a nonnegative integer and $\sum_{i=0}^{n} x_i \leq k$?
Note: I know there's a very similar question to this one, where only positive integers are counted, but it's not helpful enough for me to answer my question at the bottom.
My approach:
1. Stars and Bars problem, so we can do as follows:
$x_1 + ..... + x_n = k$
Which results in $ k+n-1 \choose n-1$
2. We can continue like this:
$x_1 + ..... + x_n = k-1 $ 
$ k+n-2 \choose n-1$
$x_1 + ..... + x_n = k-2 $ 
$ k+n-3 \choose n-1$
All the way down to
$x_1 + ..... + x_n = k-k $ 
$ k+n-k-1 \choose n-1$
Which results in the following sum: $\sum_{i=0}^{k} {k+n-i-1 \choose n-1}$
While searching online for the correct answer, the answer key gave me this: $n+k \choose n$. Unfortunately, it doesn't give much explanation as to why this is true.
Okay, so my question is as follows: Is my approach/answer correct? If not, why does it not work? Because this sounds extremely intuitive to me. 
If it is correct, how can I show that my answer is equal to that of the answer key? i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^{k} {k+n-i-1 \choose n-1} = {n+k \choose n}$

"I know there's a very similar question to this one, where only positive integers are counted, but it's not helpful enough for me to answer my question at the bottom": 1) "The bottom" should not be the title. Please edit your post: copy the title at the beginning of the body. 2) On the contrary, it is extremely helpful. Let $y_i:=x_i+1$ and consider the "vectors" $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ such that $\sum y_i\le k+n$.

Does this answer your question? Prove $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\binom{i+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$ (a.k.a. Hockey-Stick Identity) Your approach is correct, and that identity shows that $\sum_{i=0}^{k} {k+n-i-1 \choose n-1} = {n+k \choose n}$.

The alternative approach, which is much easier, is to enumerate the number of solutions to $$x_1 + x_n + c = k ~: ~c \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$$
